# getting 404 exception while rendering a View using AJAX in Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

**Goal**: To load different jsp's into a div of `main.jsp` dynamically on the basis of user click.

This is what I have done so far -

### Java Script

```
function getPageContent( pageName, containerID, path ){
$.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     url :  "getPageContent/"+pageName+".test",    
     cache : false,
     data: "path=" + path,
     success : function(response) {
         alert(response);
         $("#"+containerID).load( response );
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 
}
```

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="getPageContent/{pageName}")
public String dynamicIncludePage( ModelMap model, @PathVariable String pageName, 
        @RequestParam(value="path") String path,  HttpSession session ){

    if( pageName.equals("manageDashBoard") ){

        List<Report> reports = reportService.getAllReportsByUserID( (int)session.getAttribute("userID") );
        model.addAttribute("reports", reports);
    }


    return path+"/"+pageName;

}
```

### main.jsp

I am calling the JS method
`getPageContent( 'manageDashBoard', 'containerID', 'home' );`

path for `manageDashBoard.jsp` is --> `EVIP14ReportSS\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\home\manageDashBoard.jsp`

**But the spring is trying to locate the jsp in the below path -->  `EVIP14ReportSS\getPageContent\WEB-INF\views\home\manageDashBoard.jsp`**

Please suggest what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: what is the value of path variable  that your are sending from ajax front end? i think there might be some problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your paths are correct. You should check that anyway. 
But for sure you should change way how you are rendering page using AJAX and Spring. 
You should change return type from String to

```
public @ResponseBody JsonObjectToRender dynamicIncludePage( ModelMap model, @PathVariable String pageName, 
        @RequestParam(value="path") String path,  HttpSession session )
```

JsonObjectToRender is your custom object with some properties. In success handler JsonObjectToRender you should analyze and render part of the page depending on that object.

Comment: Of course JsonObjectToRender can be String as well. For example return "OK". In success handler if(response === "OK"){$( "#myDiv" ).innerHtml('someHTML')}